# get facebook user's display pic with cover pic into iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i wish to display a facebook user's friends' dp along with their respective cover pic. I am successful in fetching the dp only by the following code:

```
NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",[[data objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"id"]];
    NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
```

output:
[image]

but i wish to have an output like below: [WITHOUT THE UPDATE INFO AND ACTIVITY LOG BUTTONS]

[image]

How do i do this? I mean what do i need to change in the url to achieve the desired putput?

Comment: i ll surely try to do so but let me first know the answer to my question...

Comment: @z22 I have answered ur ques. Still no aceptance from you. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the url https://graph.facebook.com/kingofbliss?fields=cover

*where kingofbliss is my user id ;)*

will return the data,

```
{
   "cover": {
      "id": "379218405451233",
      "source": "http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/579338_379218405451233_1152151936_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0
   },
   "id": "100000892310267"
}
```

The source has the [url](http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/579338_379218405451233_1152151936_n.jpg) for cover image. Then proceed further...!!!